# App engine JPA date query

Tags: google-app-engine, date, jpa

Assume I have object which represents TASK. Task have due date.

How do I create query to get all tasks which are due today?

Some working code like

"select t from Task t where dueDate=:today"

will be usefull.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You assume that @Temporal is supported by Google's GAE/J plugin. It isn't, despite being reported to them over a year ago
http://code.google.com/p/datanucleus-appengine/issues/detail?id=20&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20FoundIn%20TargetRelease%20Owner%20Summary

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `dueDate` is a `Date` annotated like this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dueDate;
```

Then you can do the following query in JPQL:

```
select t from Task where t.dueDate = current_date
```

Comment: No, `current_date` returns `2010-05-21`

Comment: and sorry to say, but it not working. I test it with addedDate = current_date on just created items, and it does not return anything